# Null Pointer Exception within Android Studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

New to android here. Looked through the other answers, but still couldn't figure out what was wrong... hoping for some help here. :)

Android Studio says there is a null object reference at line 28 which is the login.setOnClick... line.

Again, sorry if this code is a mess, I am kinda winging it!

Thanks in advance!

```
public class LoginScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    // EditText mEdit;
    // TextView mText;

    private static String artist = "Artist";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                // mText.setText("Welcome "+mEdit.getText().toString()+"!");

                artist = user.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SongSelection.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public static String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/658663)

Comment: "Android Studio says there is a null object reference at line 28 which is the login.setOnClick... line." -- then `login` is presumably `null`. Perhaps you do not have a widget named `@+id/button1` in `res/layout/activity_login_screen.xml`.

Comment: Is this reported by lint (AS highlights the code even before you try to run your application) or is this an app crash (reported by AS when trying to run application)?

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` method returns null in case `Activity` is missing view with ID passed. Check whether your layout `activity_login_screen` contains view with id `button1`

Comment: Yep! You guys are right, it was the wrong ID name! Thanks for the quick responses! :)

Comment: Hi @SamMichael if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.